# How to Enable/Disable specific rest end point in spring boot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have tried to using @ConditionalOnProperty for disable/enable the spring boot endpoint, but its not working as expected. I want to disable/enable specific end points based on conditional values not the entire controller.

Comment: Can you elaborated more briefly? Or provide some code? As per i understand you just need to enable / disable endpoint based on some value Right!! How you pass that value using config file or some other way?

Comment: Yes correct, i am planning to read that value from the yml file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extract those methods to a new Controller. Then add the @ConditionalOnProperty to that Controller.

@ConditionalOnProperty works for @Bean, @Controller, @Service, ... objects, not for methods.

Comment: Right!!! Is there any other solution for do same thing for method level? Escape create new controller or bean. or put in security config file.

Comment: Is there any other way we can add this to the particular end point method?

Comment: @Albin sorry but just for fun if it's urgently required then just comment line of "@RequestMapping", and enable whenever required. ::) :)) :) But thanks i just here but never use this annotation in real life but because of your question i tried it once.

Comment: Yes correct, i commented it before, but i have to find some permanent solution for this if anything available. Meantime i will extract everything to individual controllers.